# Evaluation Form Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm taking a "cloud computing" course and have a few problems that I am trying to work through for the final project. I'll preface this with saying that i know nothing about this subject, and the few powerpoints I got off my online class don't really seem to point me in the right direction.

Basically what i need to do is have a page that allows a user to create a evaluation form. I have a general idea how to do it but I don't even know where to start in rails, I was hoping there was some stuff that Rails would do for me that might make it easier.

My assumption is that I could create a form that would allow entries for section headings.
Then when one occurs I need to allow actual question entries. then the user has the option of adding questions for the section. Then the user may add another heading, and questions.

When this "process" is complete, I need to allow a 2nd user to actually use the form for entries.

I'm assuming I somehow need to make a "string' object that will hold the text that I'm setting up, and then it sets up entries for each question.

I'm clueless where to start, I'll probably be asking a lot of questions. I don't want the solution I just need to get pointers, heading in the right direction.

the first step I'm thinking is finding a way to allow a "command" to do the equivalent of this but in the browser from another form:
 rails generate scaffold Evaluation Topic:string rating:string comments:string

Is there a way to "create" a scaffold of a form using rails in a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are mostly concerned with created forms using Rails.
Railscasts has some awesome tutorials on forms: [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/tags/15)

After viewing some of those, you should see that Rails follows an MVC policy (more information [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/)).

Since you mentioned the scaffold, it creates several controller actions.  One of those is "new" (also "edit") which I believe would be the equivalent of creating the evaluation form.
You could then create a controller action(s) for users to fill out the evaluation form.

These links should clear up a few of your questions and get you used to the rails terminology for better questions later.

Good Luck!

Comment: This looks like a really helpful site! Thank you, I wish I had known about it sooner.